# Manga or manhwa about a girl reborn as a strong fighter who tries to save her family from dead people risen from the grave

Tags: story-identification, manga, zombie, reincarnation

It was about a girl. I think she was a strong fighter and reborn, because she had memories of her mother dying and her father cheating and married someone close to her grandmother liking, like a daughter. She came back to protect her family and stop her father from cheating, and her mother from dying, but before that an event occurred in which the dead rose from the grave and made a lot of sound. She urged her father and every member of the family, including her uncle's family, to leave in the middle of the night to escape the dead, making their way to the capital of the kingdom.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, what colour was the female lead's hair?

Comment: I think it was black or brown don't remember much about hair color

Comment: it look like Chinese past historical manga because of the way the character dress